# Snowflake ODBC driver (64 bit) error while setting up DSN

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set up Data Source Name for Snowflake database connection using ‘ODBC Data Sources (64 bit)’. I have downloaded and installed Snowflake ODBC driver. I do see ‘SnowflakeDSII Driver’ in the ODBC driver list. When I try to setup Data Source Name, I am running into the following error …

[SIMBA][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the error message for key 'DSN Error' and Component ID 102:
Invalid source component ID: 102

Appreciate your help in resolving this issue.

Thanks.
Venkat.

Comment: How exactly are you setting it up? Can you add a screenshot to show the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is now resolved.
After specifying value for 'Data Source', it allowed me to create the DSN.

Thanks.
Venkat.

Comment: That issue is because the name of the DATA SOURCE is invalid or empty.

Comment: I used a DATA SOURCE value that was, apparently, too long.  After I shortened it, I stopped getting the error.